# Bash Auto Login Captive portal

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
echo "The network is up"
else
echo "The network is down"
# Starting Login
wget "nonhttpssite.com" --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --no-cache --timeout 30 -O - 2>/dev/null
fi
```

I try this code but still can't automatic after internet disconnect, using crontab execute every minute
im still confuse on wget line, login page is http://landing6.wifi.id/ but still adding other unique url example : `http://landing6.wifi.id/landing/?NG94RktRQ3drZ05SbEZqOW5yenZ1ZmtrUU8xQnRLcnorSmtVNnJhQWFpL1RMRkErVDRjd3U5Q0tJRGFwa05leDBCZ0g5VWExZlRUOFBQNXVkY0E1dUFzcVkzbWxHM0lQd2JKZVJua3NkaU5lRCtwcUhPZHI2V2kyN3JaNExSKzhQVnNYN1RTMXNyT1VUZENVeU5zMG9pcjlEdHRUa0o2T3Rab0FhZERoajhYWTFVc2RtWG9CRzJWSnYzOWhOa0h6VktqNnJKL0pSbWVlTS9NK1FabW5Wdz09`

since my mac already bypassed so i only need to open non https site to forwarded landing page, so no need to post data user/password

I will run this script on openwrt

[Animate Browsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu9lI.gif)

Comment: `wget` and MSIE don't share cookies, especially not across machines. One being able to automatically log in does not mean the other can.

Comment: im using openwrt with mac clone and reshare connection with new acces point, so after 24h dhcp release i should manualy open http site relogin, then all device which connect to my 2nd AP can acces internet

Comment: Ok... Can you give an animation that shows that wget is in fact able to do this?

Comment: so wget can't follow redirect page huh, sorry but i don't know how wget work

Comment: It can follow redirections in many cases, but I suspect it doesn't matter because these kinds of portals generally authenticate you through cookies and not mac addresses. You should look at the wget response and see what it says. If it says you need to input username/password, then you need to rethink this approach

Comment: I definitely see captive portals that whitelist based on MAC on a regular basis -- otherwise encrypted content would be prohibited. That said, I don't at all believe bash is the right tool for this particular job; using a headless browser with a JavaScript interface for interaction from other parts of the system (and there are several of those, as they're widely used for QA automation) is going to be far more flexible.

Comment: using wget http://msftconnecttest.com/, i try open index html and got redirected like gif on post
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://welcome2.wifi.id/login/?gw_id=WAG-D4-KBU&client_mac=02:02:02:02:02:03&wlan=SLOGLD00371/TLK-WI31477992-0001:@wifi.id&sessionid=0900FFFF7800F486-5AE2399C&redirect=http://msftconnecttest.com/">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    </head>
    <body>
    Please wait while you are redirected ...
    </body>
    </html>